# Unexpected Output When Accessing Redis Data in Laravel Job's failed Method

Tags: php, laravel, redis, predis

I'm working on a Laravel application that uses Redis for data storage and caching. In one of my jobs, I have a `failed` method that gets called when the job times out or fails. Within this failed method, I'm trying to access some data stored in Redis, both as a hash and a list, but I'm getting unexpected output.

Here's the relevant code from the `failed` method:

```php
public function failed($exception = null): void
{
    // ...

    if (Redis::exists($this->redisFileKey)) {
        $fileCount = Redis::llen($this->redisFileKey);
        Log::info("File count: " . $fileCount);
    }

    $orderDetails = Redis::hgetall($this->redisMainDataKey);
    Log::info("Order details: " . var_export($orderDetails, true));

    // ...
}
```

However, the output I'm getting in my logs is unexpected. For ref:

```
[2024-03-22 19:44:13] local.INFO: File count: timestamp
[2024-03-22 19:44:13] local.ERROR: array_values(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, string given {"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): array_values(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, string given at /var/www/html/vendor/predis/predis/src/Command/Redis/HGETALL.php:35)
```

I've double-checked the Redis data using a tool like Redis Insight, and the keys seem to be associated with the correct data types (a list and a hash, respectively).

PS: If the data is not enough, please let me know, I will share some more.

Comment: One more observation: If I move the logic of Logging into __construct, it works fine and the log shows right output.

Comment: Your Laravel logs will have a full stack trace showing where in your code the error originates. Looks like you're not passing an expected value somewhere.

Comment: But the Redis Insight tool shows the right data which I'm expecting @miken32

Comment: Used `php artisan tinker` and did Redis operation, things are working fine there too

Comment: just one more observation - If I place Redis::disconnect(); Redis::connect(); as the first line in the failed function, it works